# Google Spreadsheet ImportHTML and ImportXML: imported content is empty

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, stock, stockquotes

I am trying to import a table from a webpage into a google spreadsheet.

I have tried using the following two functions and both are giving me the error that the "imported content is empty".

```
=importhtml("http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=AAPL","table",1)
```

And

```
=importxml("http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=AAPL", "//*[@id='tab-profitability']/table[2]"
```

p.s. the imported data is for personal use only and will not be used against the websights policies.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the URL to be web scraped is broken and there is nothing for future readers to learn from this Q/A

Answer (score -4):

It's not possible with your url (http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=AAPL).
The command =importhtml()  it's possible if the webpage has a html table.

I give you an example :

### Example

In this URL : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Démographie_de_l'Inde
In this webpage , you can see a table .  The table is a html table

Code in the page :

```
 <table class="wikitable centre" style="text-align: center;">
<tr>
<th colspan="3" scope="col" width="60%">Évolution de la population</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Année</th>
<th>Population</th>
<th><abbr title="Croissance démographique">%±</abbr></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1951</td>
<td>361 088 000</td>
<td>—</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1961</td>
<td>439 235 000</td>
<td>+ 21,6&#160;%</td>
</tr>

<!--  Others value -->

<td colspan="3" align="center"><small>Source&#160;: <a rel="nofollow" class="external autonumber" href="http://indiabudget.nic.in/es2006-07/chapt2007/tab97.pdf">[1]</a></small></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In your Google Spreadsheet you can show data

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Démographie_de_l'Inde"; "table";
```

---

---

In this Webpage ( http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=AAPL ),  you don't have any html table so you can extract values.

Comment: in the link they mentioned I can see several HTML tables in the source code, for example...searching by:

<table class="r_table1 text2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><colgroup><col width="23%"><col width="7%" span="11"></colgroup><thead><tr><th scope="row" align="left"></th><th scope="col" align="right" id="Y0">2005-09</th><th scope="col" align="right" id="Y1">2006-09</th>.... </table>

Do you know if it's not working for a different reason? or why did you say that in that page there's not html table? Is the example above something different?

Cheers!